# jquery - ajax code , don't know what is wrong with it

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a possibility someone could tell me what is wrong with this code?

I have 4 or 5 links on a page, which load with the ajax_load function. This works all the time, when I click between them. I have 2 console.log alerts in the ajax_load function, which always show in the Google Chrome, when the links are clicked.

The problem starts when I click my 'Submit' button, which calls my form_submit function. It always works - I get a successful message in console log - but when I go back to the links, most of the time only the first console log message appears. (Before dealing with 'form_submit', the 2 messages came up.)

It doesn't get to:

```
  if (current_url_method != url + method) {   
    console.log('You got to the url + method part. But sometimes I dont get this far.'); 
    current_url_method = url + method;
```

Anyway, if someone could tell me what's wrong, I'd be grateful. Here it is:

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){

//I want to load content into the '.page-content' class, with ajax

 console.log('load ajax when document starts. This always works.'); 
  var ajax_loaded = (function(response) {        

    $(".page-content")

     .html($(response).filter(".page-content"));       

    $(".page-content .ajax").on("click",ajax_load);  



   });

//use the ajax function below for submitting forms

var form_submit = (function(e) {
  console.log('form_submit is working. This always works.');         
  e.preventDefault();               

  var url = $(this).attr("action");       
  var method = $(this).attr("method");      


  var data = {}                 
  $(this).find("input, textarea, select").each(function(i){
    var name = $(this).attr("name");      
    var value = $(this).val();          

    data[name] =value;              

  }); 

  $.ajax({                    
    "url": url,                 
    "type": method,                
    "data": data,               
    "success": ajax_loaded,
    "error": function () {alert("bad");}    
  });

});

//the function below is called by links that are described 
//with the class 'ajax', or are in the div 'menu' 

var history = [];                 

var current_url_method;               

var ajax_load = (function(e) {  


console.log('load ajax on clicks. This always works.');         
  e.preventDefault();               


  history.push(this);               
  var url =$(this).attr("href");          
  var method = $(this).attr("data-method");   

  if (current_url_method != url + method) {   
    console.log('You got to the url + method part. But sometimes I dont get this far.'); 
    current_url_method = url + method;      

$.ajax({                  
  url: url,               
  type: method,  
  async: false,                       
  success: ajax_loaded       
});
   }

});


//monitor for clicks from menu div, or with
//the ajax class, or the 'submit button'.
//why the trigger?

$("#menu a").on("click",ajax_load);
$(".ajax").on("click",ajax_load);
$("#menu a.main").trigger("click");
$(".search-box form").on("submit", form_submit);


});
```

Comment: There's no `history.push()` that I can find, it's `history.pushState()`.

Comment: When I do that I get Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'pushState' , which I wasn;t getting before.

Comment: In Chrome I get `TypeError: Object #<History> has no method 'push'` when I type `history.push("foo")` in the console.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I'm certainly no expert - got this code off someone else, but maybe we're talking about 2 different things? There's a jquery push function too. It adds an element on the end of the array and expands the array. And in my code, history is defined as an array.

Comment: I didn't see the `var history` declaration; there's a global `history` object that's used to manipulate the browser's Back and Forward list.

Comment: The message that you sometimes don't get is only logged if the URL+method of the link you click on is different from the one that was clicked on previously. Couldn't they be the same sometimes, and that's why you don't get the message?

Comment: Yes! Half an hour ago I actually commented out that if block: if (current_url_method != url + method)..etc...and it works now - but I wasn't sure what it was doing, so thanks for telling me. Put that last comment in an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. By the way, do you think it would be a big job to change my code so the 'Back' and 'Forward' buttons work on my pages? I think that pushState function might be the right direction....

Comment: You might want to take a look at how GitHub does its forward/back functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log message is only displayed in the following condition:

```
if (current_url_method != url + method) {
```

If you click on a link with the same URL+method as the previous one, that condition won't be true and you won't get a log message. But the AJAX call after it will still take place.

If you want the log mesage all the time, take the `console.log()` call out of that `if()` block. But then there doesn't seem to be any reason for the `current_url_method` variable; the only thing it's used for is deciding whether to log this message.

Comment: Cheers Barmar, that was the problem.

Comment: Although, the console.log message wasn't my concern. that was a test to sort out the problem. The problem was that if I clicked the same link twice, the next link would not load. I had to click it again for it to load.

Comment: Your messed up indentation confused me, I didn't realize the `$.ajax` was inside the `if`. If you want people to understand your code and help you competently, you need to do your part and at least make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is the closure. Try:

```
var ajax_loaded = function(response) { 
    $(".page-content") .html($(response).filter(".page-content")); 
    $(".page-content .ajax").on("click",ajax_load); 
};
```

Comment: No, that didn't do it. Still the same problem. Thanks though.

Comment: Try the same on the var ajax_load function also.

Comment: Thought it sorted the problem but didn't, sorry. Thanks again all the same.